# Computing Sum of an Interesting Series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $f_{n}=\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{n}(e^{kx}-1)$ with $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N^{*}}$ and define :
$$
a_{n}=f_{n}^{(n)}(0)\qquad\text{and}\qquad b_{n}=f_{n}^{(n+1)}(0)
$$
How can we show that :
$$
\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}=2-\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}
$$

Comment: What have you tried? It's easy to find the explicit value of $a_n$, and not much harder for $b_n$ (using the Taylor series for $e^{kx}$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a_{n}=(n!)^{2}$

$\displaystyle b_{n}=\frac{n(n+1)^{2}(n!)^{2}}{4}$

This can be seen if you rewrite $f_{n}(x)$ as :
$$f_{n}(x) :=n!x^{n}\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{e^{kx}-1}{kx}$$ and then apply the general Leibniz rule.